# Change the sort order in Thunderbird on multiple columns

Tags: email, thunderbird, sorting

I would like to be able to sort (order by) email messages based on three (3) of the columns.

Specifically at the top would be Starred, then Unread and then by Age (Newest at the top) (with Starred and Unread in newest to oldest order if possible).

Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know this is still until today not possible. Sorting by two columns is possible (see mashup's answer). Sadly we are out of luck when sorting by three or more columns...

I would love to hear if someone even knows an add-on that enables this.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort by two columns, e.g. first sort by date clicking the column and then sort by attachment or another column and it will be sorted properly.

For more columns I would either use an addon or simply perform a search query using filters

Comment: What kind of addon do you think will fit such requirements?

Comment: @Pasha There doesn’t seem to be one.